# Vue 2 - Create form with abstract v-model property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new with Vue and i'm trying to create a dynamic `<form>` on my project.

At this moment, i want to use v-model on inputs that are allocated on `<slot>` in that `<form>`. The problem is, the model is not instantiated and i want to send it as param on `<form>`.

Check some code of what i want, maybe it's easy to understand:

foo.blade.php:

```
<custom-form 
  :model="{
            name: null,
            email: null,
            body: null,
          }" 
  url="url/foo">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input id="name" name="name" v-model="model.name">
 </div>
</custom-form>
```

CustomForm.vue:

```
<script>
  export default {
     props: ['model','url']
  }
</script>
```

The error says that cannot read name from null. (model is not instantiated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use data from a component in it's slot, you need to use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("custom-form", {
  props: ["model", "url"],
  template: `
    <form :action="url">
      <slot :model="model"/>
    </form>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    model: {
      name: null,
      email: null,
      body: null,
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <custom-form :model="model" url="url/foo">
    <template slot-scope="props">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="name" name="name" v-model="props.model.name">
      </div>
    </template>
  </custom-form>
  <hr> {{model}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to use `scoped-slot`. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots

The idea is that in the child component you would declare somethings like:

```
<slot :model="model">...</slot>
```

And in the parent:

```
<custom-form 
  :model="{
            name: null,
            email: null,
            body: null,
          }" 
  url="url/foo">
 <div scop-slot="props" class="form-group">
  <input id="name" name="name" v-model="props.model.name">
 </div>
</custom-form>
```